# Please Explain the ambiguity in pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{ int x[3][5]={{1,2,10,4,5},{6,7,1,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}};


printf("%d\n",x); 
printf("%d\n",*x); }
```

Here first printf will print the address of first element.
So why not the second printf prints the value at the address x i.e the first value.
To print the value I need to write **x.

Comment: Are you sure first printf will print address rather than value??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For pointers, `x[0]` is the same as `*x`. It follows from this that `*x[0]` is the same as `**x`.

In `*x[0]`:

`x` is a `int[3][5]`, which gets converted to `int(*)[5]` when used in expression. So x[0] is lvalue of type `int[5]` (the first 5-element "row"), which gets once again converted to `int*`, and dereferenced to its first element.

`*x` is evaluated along the same lines, except the first dereference is done with an asterisk (as opposed to indexing), and there is no second dereference, so we end up with lvalue of type `int[5]`, which is passed to `printf` as a pointer to its first element.

Comment: yeah,, but i get the address when i print "x" so when i do the operation *x i should get the value stored at that address...

Comment: Yes and no. You really get the value stored at the address, this is the "lvalue of type `int[5]`" I was talking about. However, Arrays are not first class in C, they are passed to functions as pointers to their first element. So `printf` gets the pointer to the first `int` of the 5, which has the same address as the address of the first element of `x`. IOW, `(void*)x == (void*)*x` and that's what you see.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays, when used as arguments to functions, decay into pointers to the first element of the array.  That being said, the type of object that `x` decays into is a pointer to the first sub-array, which is a pointer to an array of `int`, or basically `int (*)[5]`.  When you call `printf("%d\n",*x)`, you are not feeding an integer value to `printf`, but rather a pointer to the first sub-array of `x`.  Since that sub-array will also decay to a pointer to the first sub-array's element, you can do `**x` to dereference that subsequent pointer and get at the first element of the first sub-array of `x`.  This is effectively the same thing as `*x[0]`, which by operator precedence will index into the first sub-array of `x`, and then dereference the pointer to the first sub-array's element that the first sub-array will decay into.

Answer (score 0):

Because of type of `*x` is 'pointer to array of 5 ints'. So, you need one more dereference to get the first element

PS:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

typedef int arr[5]; // can't compile if put arr[4] here
void foo(arr& x)
{
}

int main()
{
  int x[3][5]={{1,2,10,4,5},{6,7,1,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}};

  std::cout << typeid(*x).name() << std::endl;// output: int [5]

  foo(x[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The type of `*x` is "pointer to `int`" (`int *`). It's `x` itself, after the array type decays to a pointer in an expression, that has type "pointer to array of 5 `int`s".

Comment: Erm, `*x` has type "array of 5 ints", so I was slightly wrong. In most contexts, that decays to type "pointer to int". It most certainly does not have type "pointer to array of 5 ints" in any interpretation.

Comment: Yes, i had changed my original message and added some 'proof'.

Comment: Well your program is C++ not C, so it's not really "proof" of anything. However it does agree with my second comment.

Answer (score -1):

Think about a 2-d array as an array of pointers, with each element in the array pointing to the first element in another array.  When you dereference `x`, you get the value that is in the memory location pointed to by x... a pointer to the first `int` in an array of `int`s.  When you dereference that pointer, you will get the first element.

Comment: This isn't accurate. You can certainly have an effective 2-d jagged array by having an array of pointers, but the actual storage is just row-by-row sequentially, with the dereferencing done by multiplication.

Comment: @Yuliy: I understand that that is not how it is implemented, but it is an easy way to understand why you need to dereference twice.

Comment: @Daniel: Yuliy's point stands. There's already enough confusion among C newbies about this, and already too many trying to allocate a "two dimensional array" as an array of pointers, that any risk of furthering this misunderstanding should be avoided.