# 2d boolean array initialization in c++

Tags: c++, initialization, multidimensional-array

I don't use C that much and I recently got confused about 2d array initialization problem. I need to debug somebody's code and stuck in the following(her original code):

```
const int location_num = 10000;
bool **location_matrix;
if (node_locations)
    {
        location_matrix = (bool **)malloc(location_num*sizeof(bool *));
        if (!location_matrix)
        {
                cout<<"error 1 allocating location_matrix" << endl;
                exit;
        }
        for (i=0; i<location_num; i++)
        {
                location_matrix[i] = (bool *) malloc(location_num*sizeof(bool ));
                if (!location_matrix[i])
                {
                        cout<<"error 2 allocating location_matrix" << endl;
                        exit;
                }
                for (j=0; j<location_num; j++)
                        location_matrix[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
```

I thought is was redundant, so I changed it to the following:

`location_matrix[location_num][location_num] = { {false} };`

However, segmentation fault happens at runtime. 
My question is: how does the above code fail? If it looks right, what's the difference between dynamically allocation and static allocation? Is it just because the dimension might not be constant, so we need to do it dynamically?
Also, just for curiosity, how do I malloc 2d array that stores pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc(n * sizeof(T))` instead of `new T[n]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually don't see anything wrong with the code.

The following code doesn't work because `location_matrix` is not allocated:

```
location_matrix[location_num][location_num] = { {false} };
```

GCC will allow the following (as an extension):

```
bool location_matrix[location_num][location_num] = { {false} };
```

But it will blow your stack because `10000 x 10000` is too large.

Currently, your code uses dynamic allocation. That's the correct way to do it because the matrix is too large to be done as a static array (and may overrun the stack).

As for your last question, "how to make a 2d array that stores pointers": It can be done almost the same way as your current code. Just change `bool` to `int*`.

So a 2D array of NULL `int` pointers will look like this:

```
int ***location_matrix;
if (node_locations)
{
    location_matrix = (int***)malloc(location_num*sizeof(int**));
    if (!location_matrix)
    {
            cout<<"error 1 allocating location_matrix" << endl;
            exit;
    }
    for (i=0; i<location_num; i++)
    {
            location_matrix[i] = (int**) malloc(location_num*sizeof(int*));
            if (!location_matrix[i])
            {
                    cout<<"error 2 allocating location_matrix" << endl;
                    exit;
            }
            for (j=0; j<location_num; j++)
                    location_matrix[i][j] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `location_num` is a compile-time initialised local `const int` so this code should work in C++ (even w/o compiler extensions), unless I’m momentarily confused.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I was referring to the array initializer as the GCC extension.

Comment: The initialiser looks OK to me, too. Now, you’re of course right about the size.

Answer (score 4):

The change would likely require about 100MB (`10,000 * 10,000 * 1`) on the stack, so the segmentation fault was likely due to a stack overflow.

**Edit**  I originally stated 400MB in the answer, but @Mooing Duck points out bool will likely be 1 byte.  I was thinking the Win32 BOOL (for no real reason at all), which is typedefed to an int.

Comment: I don't know about c, but in c++ when it runs out of memory, the system will print "bad alloc", so are you saying that segmentation fault can also represent stack overflow in c?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but an "allocation" on the stack is basically an addition to the stack pointer (or subtraction ... I forget now if it typically goes up or down).  If there is no stack checking enabled, then any reads/writes to that local variable that goes past the valid stack will be accessing memory that is outside the valid address space, which may result in the segmentation fault.

Comment: @MarkWilkins: I think (in most implementaitons) a bool is only 1 byte.  Still, StackOverflow seems likely.

Comment: @Mooing Duck:  That is probably true.  I will edit it.  I was basing it (for no good reason) on the Win32 BOOL, which is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The standard library is your friend.

```
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
  int location_num = 1000;
  std::vector<std::vector<bool> > location_matrix(location_num, std::vector<bool>(location_num, false));
}
```

Comment: Be aware that vector<bool> has issues - it is not an array of bools really.  The standard library specialized vector<bool> so it packs bits into an attempt at a dynamic bitset.  If you really need an array of bools so that .data() gives you a pointer to bool* then put std::deque<bool> inside.

Answer (score 2):

Second, the array is likely too large to fit on the stack, so you'd need to dynamically allocate it -- but you can simplify the code as long as the [difference between a 2-dimensional array and an array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7586702/929459) won't be an issue (as it would be if you needed to pass the array to a function or use pointer arithmetic with it).

You could use something like this:

```
bool (*location_matrix)[location_num];

location_matrix = (bool (*)[location_num])calloc( location_num, 
                                                  location_num * sizeof(bool) );
```

...which allocates space for the whole two-dimensional array and gives a pointer to an array of `bool` arrays with `location_num` elements each.