# typecasting int [n][m] to int ** gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, casting, segmentation-fault

Why does this code give a segmentation fault:

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;
int a[n][m];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cin >> a[i][j];

int ** x = (int **) a;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        cout << x[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.9.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer

Comment: `int a[n][m]` is of type `int[][m]` which is different from `int**`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Actually, the code isn't standard C++ anyway, so it is hard to say what the type of `int[n][m]` is.

Comment: Actually, I was looking in the C tag, so I assumed C. I'm removing the C tag since the code is clearly C++.