# How do you pass a 2D array of objects to a function? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, 2d

So I have this:

```
class Component
{
public:
   int label;
   int order;
};
```

Later in my code I created a 2D array named

```
Component pixel[][cap]
```

and initialized its size with user input. Now I am trying to pass it to my function named imageDFS. I tried to use

```
void imageDFS(Component **)
```

and

```
imageDFS(pixel)
```

but I still receive compiling (codeblocks) errors.

Comment: [A 2D array cannot be converted to a pointer-to-a-pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer)

Comment: You possibly want to make the argument `Component (*namegoeshere)[cap]`. Or `Component namegoeshere[][cap]` if you prefer the array syntax.

Comment: I've tried your second suggestion and received the same error.