# Trouble working with 2d array passed by reference C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am working on an assignment and I am having trouble figuring out how to use this 2d array which was passed by reference.

What I am given is this

```
int main(){
//cap and flow initialized 
maximum_flow(1000, &(cap[0][0]), &(flow[0][0]));

}
```

So I wanted to copy the contents of cap over to another 2d array I dynamically allocated, but after hitting an error I decided to print out the values I have in `cap2` and `capacity`, I'm not getting back all the values that I should.

```
void maximum_flow(int n, int *capacity, int *flow){
    int **cap2;
    cap2 = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int *)*n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cap2[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {   
          cap2[i][j] = (*(capacity + i*n + j));
          (*(flow + i*n + j)) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read some course about pointer in C :/ There is **no** reference in C.

Comment: This is not a 2D array, it is a heap fragmentation... thing. Instead of this slow, error-prone look-up table, use a 2D array. [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c)

Comment: How are `cap` and `flow` declared?

Comment: I don't see were you "print out the values _you_ have in `cap2` and `capacity`". Also, use a debugger to run your program step by step and find where error occurs

Comment: A two-dimensional array and a pointer-to-pointer is not the same thing in C. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer

Comment: What does "not getting back all the values that I should" mean?

Comment: Please include initialization of `cap` and `flow` in your `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be a terribly useful answer, since your code doesn't actually show the problem described; based on what's presented, I see no obvious reason why `cap` and `cap2` shouldn't have the same contents by the end of the `maximum_flow` function.  But I'd like to offer some background and a suggestion.

I'm going to assume `cap` and `flow` are declared as `n` by `n` arrays of `int` in `main`, where `n` is known at compile time.

The reason your instructor is using this interface is that passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments is problematic in C.  Remember that unless it's the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaraiton, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So, assuming a declaration like

```
int cap[10][10];
int flow[10][10];
```

the *expressions* `cap` and `flow` will each "decay" to type `int (*)[10]` (pointer to 10-element array of `int`).  So if you wrote your function *call* as

```
maximum_flow( 1000, cap, flow );
```

then the function *definition* would have to be written as

```
void maximum_flow( int n, int (*cap)[10], int (*flow)[10] ) { ... }
```

or

```
void maximum_flow( int n, int cap[][10], int flow[][10] ) { ... }
```

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[][N]` and `T (*a)[N]` mean the same thing.

The size of the outer dimension *has* to be specified in the array pointer declaration, and the problem is that a pointer to a 10-element array is a different, *incompatible* type from a pointer to an any-value-other-than-10-element array; thus, `maximum_flow` could only ever be used for `N` x 10-element arrays, limiting its usefulness.  One way around this problem is to have the function receive an explicit pointer to the first element, and treat that pointer as a 1D array of size `N * M`.

Long story short, since you're treating your input parameters as 1D arrays, you are probably better off creating `cap2` as a 1D array as well:

```
int *cap2 = malloc( sizeof *cap2 * n * n );
...
cap2[i * n + j] = capacity[i * n + j]; // use array subscript notation instead
flow[i * n + j] = 0;                   // of explicit dereferences
```

From the code you've posted, it's not clear what `maximum_flow` is supposed to do, nor why you need `cap2`.  Note also that at some point you need to `free` the memory allocated to `cap2`, otherwise you have a memory leak.

If you're using a C99 or later compiler, you should be able to use a variable-length array instead of `malloc`:

```
int cap2[n * n]; // or int cap2[n][n], but like I said above, if you're 
                 // treating your inputs as 1D arrays, you should also treat
                 // cap2 as a 1D array.
```

The advantage of a VLA is that you don't need to know the size at compile time, and it's treated like any other `auto` variable, meaning the memory for it will be released when the function exits.

The disadvantage of a VLA is that you can't use it as anything *but* a local variable; you can't have a VLA as a struct or union member, nor can you declare one `static` or at file scope.  Neither can you explicitly initialize a VLA.