# Trying to access address of 2D array in C and getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-address

I'm a beginner with C, and I'm a little confused about pointers and how they are passed to other functions. I'm working on a project and in my main function, I malloc a 2D array of chars representing a game board.

```
// In main, allocate 2D array   
char **board = malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    board[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(char)); 
}
```

A function can be called later which will load a saved version of the game, and thus re-malloc my board variable.

```
void stringToGame(char ***board, int *rows, int *cols, int *turn, int *winLength) {
    // Set new values for rows and cols based on file
    ...

    // Malloc board 
    *board = malloc(*rows * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < *rows; i++) {
        *board[i] = malloc(*cols * sizeof(char));   
    }

}
```

When I call the stringToGame method in my main function, I'm passing the address of the board.

```
stringToGame(&board, &rows, &cols, &turn, &winLength);
```

Passing the board's address is causing a segmentation fault and I have no idea why.

As a secondary question, do I need to free() my old 2D array for the board before I malloc a new one?

Comment: It would make your code easier to manage if you had a dedicated function  for allocating/reallocating the board.

Comment: @M.M That's the plan as soon as I can get it working at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
*board[i] = malloc(*cols * sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
(*board)[i] = malloc(*cols * sizeof(char));
```

because the array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*` and hence will execute first but you need the opposite to happen, i.e, first `*`, then `[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you have declared is not a `2-d array`, it's a double pointer. There is a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer) between these two.

Second, you don't need to pass the address of the array to the function, since arrays are passed by reference anyways. You can simply pass a double-pointer to your function after malloc-ing it.

```
stringToGame(board, &rows, &cols, &turn, &winLength);
```

And the answer to your secondary question, yes, you should `free` your old pointer first, before you malloc it again, otherwise your program will have a memory leak. The first value of `board` will be lost and you will not be able to free it.

Comment: The `stringToGame` function reallocates the board, so passing `board` by value would not work