# Floodfill algorithm C - return double array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, return-type, flood-fill

Given a double array of random values mod 5 and a value X and a position in the array, I have to change the position's value and all its neighbors to X.
I'm doing it recursively. I think the idea is correct, however I must be messing with the return statement and the assignment using the recursive call.
When compiling I get
  note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[8]'

also, if I use the function in the main I get
    warning: passing argument 1 of 'floodfill' from incompatible pointer type
   table = floodfill( table, i, j, r );

error: assignment to expression with array type
   table = floodfill( table, i, j, r );

where table is the table on which the algorithm has to be executed

```
int ** floodfill ( int **tab, int i, int j, int v)
{
  /*if statement to make the values to the right of the specified position
  equal to the specified value*/
  if ( tab[i][j+1] == tab[i][j] )
  {
      /*the assignment is recursive*/
       tab = floodfill ( tab, i, j+1, v);
  }
  /*this assignment is executed after each of the values to the
  right of tab[i][j] are changed to v*/
  tab[i][j] = v;

  /*returns the tab with the specified position changed*/
  return tab;
}
```

Obviously the code is incomplete (no malloc, no check for out-of-bound position and only floodfill of right values) for the sake of brevity , but for what concerns my problem there should be everything.

Comment: What's your question? That's not clear.

Comment: How is `table` declared? Are you confusing a 2d array and a pointer to pointer to T? The warning indicates that that is the case. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, C pointers point to buffers which you can manipulate in place. They don't pass whole buffers by value. Returning an int ** is pointless, caller already has the information.

Secondly, you want to floodfill a value u with a new value, v. u might be the pixel value you first call, in which case the fist call is special. Easier to pass it in - so the function converts all values u and neighbours to value v. If the value to tab[i][j] is not u, return. Otherwise floodfill in all four directions. It's a bit heavy on the stack, but should work

```
void floodfill(int **tab, int u, int v, int i int j)
{
   if(tab[i][j] == u)
   {
       tab[i][j[ = v;
       floodfill(tab, u, v, i+1, ,j);
       floodfill(tab, u, v, i-1, j);
       floodfill(tab, u, v, i, j -1);
       floodfill(tab, u, v, i, j +1);
   }
}
```