# Why can't a 2D array passed as input argument to a function cannot be declared as int** in its function declaration?

Tags: c, arrays

If suppose I have two arrays `arr` a 1D array and `brr` a 2D array and I want to pass these arrays as input to functions

In case of a  1D :

`void fun(int*);` OR  `void fun(int[]); //both declarations are allowed`

```
fun(arr);//call for 1D

void fun(int *ptr)
{
 //function def of 1D
}
```

But  in case of a 2D Array:

```
void fun(int[][]); //allowed
void fun(int**);  //this is not allowed **WHY so?**
```

While the call and definitions are similar to the previous 1D array

```
fun(brr);//call

void fun(int **ptr2)
{
 //code
}
```

Comment: [An array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to pointer (or array of pointers)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558).

Comment: Related, if not dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer

Answer (score 1):

This is because by convention a pointer to an array is considered as a qualified pointer to the first element of type in many occasions especially on function passed parameters.

You can consult the **ISO/IEC 9899:2011** § **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) - Semantics**:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
>   those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If
>   the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
>   corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
>   element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
>   size expression.

But a declaration of type `int[][]` instead of `int**`is not interchangeable because while the first refers to a 2D array, and it will be silently changed by the compiler to a pointer to the first element of the 2D array, the second means a **pointer to pointer of int**, that is not compatible with a 2D array.

Sometime people are induced in confusion by pseudo 2D arrays defined dynamically as follows:

```
int **My_2D_array = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2);  //We are allocating 2 pointers to int
My_2D_array[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);  //We allocate the first dimension space
My_2D_array[1] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);  //We allocate the second dimension space
```

In this case the name `My_2D_array` will be referred as the address of the first element of an array of 2 pointers to int, and the use of the `[]` operator will return the first pointer in the pointers array. Applying again the operator `[]` onto the pointer just obtained, and again used as the address of the first element of a monodimensional array of int's, will returs an int:

```
int my_int = My_2D_array[0][1];  //mimics a bidimensional array, but isn't!
```