# C How do I print the size of a string in array of strings

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    char** a = {"bob", "alex", "john"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf('%d', sizeof(a[i]));
    }
}
```

What I try to do here, is to initialize an array of string, iterate through it and print the size for each word of it. But I get segmentation error. What is wrong with my approach ?

Comment: I recommend you to see accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746434/double-pointer-vs-array-of-pointersarray-vs-array/33748099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double pointer vs array of pointers(\*\*array vs \*array\[\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746434/double-pointer-vs-array-of-pointersarray-vs-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* a[3] = {"bob", "alex", "john"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", strlen(a[i]));
    }
}
```

Notice that the differences are `char* a[3]` instead of `char**`, `"%d"` instead of `'%d'` and `strlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: Nit-pick: `strlen()` returns a value of type `size_t`. The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.