# Why doesn't the C double asterisk work for creating a 2D array?

Tags: c, pointers

Why does this work:

```
char *name = "steven";
```

but this doesn't:

```
char **names = {"steven", "randy", "ben"};
```

Or, why does this work:

```
char *names[] = {"steven", "randy", "ben"};
```

but, again, this doesn't:

```
char **names = {"steven", "randy", "ben"};
```

Comment: TLDR:  because `char **names` **does not refer to a 2D array**, no matter what you've been told.  See [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double pointer vs array of pointers(\*\*array vs \*array\[\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746434/double-pointer-vs-array-of-pointersarray-vs-array)

Comment: Thanks, yes, both these links are helpful. So when you have char

Comment: So when you have char *names[] = {"bob", ...}, is names a pointer?

Comment: No, the `[]` means that `names` is an array, and the `char *` means that the array contains pointers to `char`

Comment: Thanks! I think that is what I was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char **p` is not a 2D array, it is a pointer to a pointer to a character. However, you can have more pointers and more characters following, resembling a kind of model of a 2D structure of characters.

C compiler interpret `{ "steven" }` as a 1D array of characters, because the braces are optional (standard chapter 6.7.9 paragraph 14).

As you tried, you can declare an array of pointers to a character by `char *p[]`.

But if you want to have that pointer (to pointers to characters), you need to tell your compiler. The address of an array can be assigned to the pointer.

```c
char **p = (char *[]){ "steven", "randy", "ben", };
```

Additional note: Since string literals are unmutable, you better add a `const` for the characters. And since the address of these unnamed string literals are constant, too, you can provide another one.

```c
const char * const *p = (const char * const []){ "steven", "randy", "ben", };
```

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in saying the  (char *[]){ "steven", "randy", "ben", } is type casting?

Comment: Well, it's a _compound literal_, see chapter 6.5.2.5. The standard differentiates it from a cast.

Comment: It's very different from a cast. It *creates* (allocates memory for) an object; that object has a defined lifetime which you must be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I also wondered, what if I could answer you in the simplest way possible.

**Why are you confused?**

*A simple pointer* to integer for example allocated *with 8 cells*, acts in the same way as *an array has a dimension of 8 cells.*
The only difference, that you can't see, is that a pointer that has 8 cells allocated is on a part of the memory that is called the **HEAP**, while a variable of type int tab[8] is allocated on the **STACK**.
*Indeed, since the cells are linked in memory, it is easy to imagine that a pointer and an array whose first cell address is sent are the same thing.*

**Why it doesn't work in the other case**

However, when the idea comes to associate (** and [][])
Let's take the example of an int ** ;

```
int **tab;

tab = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);
//secure malloc do not forget
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
   //secure malloc do not forget
}
```

and an

`int[4][3];`

You have a problem.
To imagine, a double array type follows itself in memory, because it is the very principle of arrays.

[image: Memoy double array on Stack]

While a double pointer has first 4 cells of type int * allocated (which follow each other in memory) and then each pointer of these 4 cells, each points to a memory area of 3 ints which follow each other. But the whole thing does not follow each other in the memory!

[image: Memory double pointer on Heap]

**A way that may interest you**

One thing you can do instead is to create an `int ptr(*)[3];`
which can point to the first element of an array of size 3, i.e. the address of an array `[4][3]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for a scalar object may not contain more than one item.

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> 2     No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
> being initialized.
> ...
> 11     The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The
> initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type
> constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar
> to be the unqualified version of its declared type

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

`char **names` declares a single, scalar object, not an array, so any initializer for it must only contain a single item.  That initializer may be a single string (`"steven"`), optionally enclosed in braces (`{ "steven" }`).  However, it may not be a *list* of initializers.